# Could not find equation of function from data

Tags: analysis, graphing-functions

I have a problem to find equation of function of my data:

0.00    0.007

0.20    0.041

0.40    0.165

0.60    0.449

0.80    0.816

1.00    0.982

1.20    0.741

1.40    0.212

1.60    -0.362

1.80    -0.808

2.00    -0.975

2.20    -0.774

2.40    -0.290

2.60    0.290

2.80    0.775

3.00    0.982

3.20    0.849

3.40    0.527

3.60    0.237

3.80    0.077

4.00    0.018

4.20    0.003

4.40    0.002

4.60    0.001

4.80    0.001

5.00    0.001

The shape of curve is on image.

I suggest that there are three extreme, and two radix x1 and x2.

I need this shape to make an optimalization of function data, but I don´t know the shape of equation to fit the parameter of function.

Does anyone know some way around this?

Thanks

Paul!

[image: truncated picture]

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the four parameters of the function 
$$f(r,a,b,c):=-\left(a-b\,(x-r)^4\right)\;e^{-c\,(x-r)^2}$$
($b\,(x-r)^2$ seemed too weak) I obtained for $f(2.02,1,12,2.4)$ :

[image: approximation]

Still not perfect but it may provide additional inspiration!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped @Paul! To get a more accurate answer you may prefer $$\,f(r,a,b,c,d):=-\left(a-b\,(x-r)^2-c\,(x-r)^4\right)\;e^{-d\,(x-r)^2}$$ If the horizontal tangents at height $\pm 1$ are important for you (and if you want to change arbitrary the extremums) you could try [Cubic Hermite splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) but in this case the function will be composed of cubics defined by intervals. Excellent continuation,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. May I ask how you arrive to such a function ? Cheers :) :) :)

Comment: Yes of course @Claude (thanks for the interest!). This made me think to the [atomic orbital 3s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Qualitative_understanding_of_shapes) and I modified a little the related radial equation. Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. When I think that I was a quantum-mechanicist and that I missed that !! Shame on me and $bravo !$.